# Listing the elements of $U(\mathbb{Z}_{54})$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

The set of all integers modulo $q$ is denoted by $\mathbb{Z}_q$. When equipped with multiplication modulo $q$, has the structure of a commutative monoid, the identity element being equivalence class $1$.  $Q$ is a natural number, $≥ 2$.

Really struggling with this question, Im fairly sure the elements are all the odd numbers, less the divisors of $54 (2,3,6,9,18,27)$? But am unsure how to write this properly. Also I seem to think that the elements will stop at $17$? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know about the group of units? $U(\mathbb{Z}_n)=\{1\le m\le n\vert \gcd(m,n)=1\}$? See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n)

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Consider the set $S_{n}=\{1\le m\le n\vert \gcd(m,n)=1\}$.

**Note** that if $\gcd(m,n)=1,\,\,\exists\text{ integers }p,q$ such that.

$mq+pn=1$ (as gcd can be expressed as a linear combination)

Reduce both sides modulo $n$. Can you see where to go from here?

> **EDIT:**
>
> First, consider the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{54}$. If $i\in \mathbb{Z}_{54}$ such that $\gcd(i,54)=d>1$, then $i$ is a **zero divisor** $\Big($$\because\,\,\, i\cdot\frac nd=0$ $\Big)$ and hence $i$ cannot be a unit **(why?)**
>
> > **Important**: If $i$ had a multiplicative inverse then this would imply $\frac nd\text=\,0$ which is clearly not the case.
>
> Now, claim that if $\gcd(i,54)=1$, then $i$ is a unit.
>
> Suppose $\gcd(i,54)=1$. Then $\exists\,\, p\,,\,q\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $ip+54q=1$ or $(ip)\pmod{54}=1$ and hence, $i^{-1}=p$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{54}$.

Thus we have `i is a unit` $\iff$ `gcd(i,54)=1`

So the set of units is $S_{54}$, where $S_n$ is as defined in the first step.

Comment: Not at all, can you recommend any good websites to have a look at? the text book i have been using (Jordan and Jordan - Groups) is very blasé about the subject.

Comment: @joe This seems to be exactly the answer you need. You will have to say what exactly you don't get about it, or else it is hard to see what else one can say to explain.

Comment: so do i take mq + pn = 1, and then substitute 54 in? and then deterrine all possible solutions? I'm not sure what 'reduce modulo n' means, and can't find much about it online

Comment: If $\gcd(m,n)=1$, then $mq\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ so $m$ has an inverse! (Note: All elements of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ are either a zero divisor or a unit). Thus $U(\mathbb{Z}_n)=S$, I am sure you can construct it..

Comment: Im sorry but that still means nothing to me. what is mq?

Comment: $q$ is the multiplicative inverse of $m$ modulo $n$. Are you aware of the theorem that states, "the g.c.d can be expressed as a linear combination of the two numbers"?

Comment: yeh but it doesn't mean anything to me

Comment: Ok. Read [this](http://www.uow.edu.au/~bmaloney/wuct121/NumbersWeek7Lecture2.pdf). Now re-read the fourth comment. Now the proof above shows that whenever $m<n\text{ and }\gcd(m,n)=1$, then $\exists q\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $mq\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ *(i.e. $m$ is a unit/has an inverse i.e. $m\in U(\mathbb{Z}_{54})$)*. I hope this helps. @Joe

Comment: mate could you not just tell me from the beginning each step? I've read everything i can find and have been stuck on this 3 mark question for days and your cryptic responses just aren't helping in the slightest

Comment: @Joe: Check the answer now!

Comment: can you please just tell me exactly what units are inside the set and why? i cannot make head or tail of your clues despite trying for 2 weeks

Comment: I don't think you're trying hard enough. I have written the whole proof above showing $i$ is a unit iff $\gcd(i,54)=1$. (If you didn't realise, my latest edit made it a proper proof). The answer is $S_{54}=\{1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,25,29,31,35,37,41,43,47,49,53\} $